# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Git - Missing Project Explorer Menu

Tags: git, visual-studio

We recently switched to GIT provider for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. One of my colleague isn't able to see all project menu items (e.g. missing Pull Request, Work Items, Builds) and also related work items input fields.

[image]

Unsure if this is a permission issue or configuration issue. Any idea?

Comment: solution already?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue simply click on Connect button 2nd from right (Team explorer menu) and close the repo.